# Batch Echo's HTML5 - Doesn't export?

Tags: html, batch-file, echo

Hello Stackoverflow people,
I have been trying to make custom HTML files with echo in batch.
I am now on a part that doesnt work so im here to ask you to help me...
This is my code:

```
echo        ^<a href="./About.html"^>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;About^</a^> ^>^>index.html
echo        ^<a href="./support.html"^>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Help^</a^> ^>^>index.html
echo        ^<a href="./security.html"^>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Security^</a^> ^>^>index.html
```

And in someway it doesnt export to index.html... I would like some help on this problem,

- Luseres

Comment: The ampersand is a special character as well as the two you've already escaped. _(you shouldn't have escaped the last two of those in each line either)_

Comment: @Compo Thank you, It worked :). Maybe you can add your comment as awnser so I can check it so you get some reputation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "nbsp=^&nbsp;"
(
echo        ^<a href="./About.html"^>%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%About^</a^>
echo        ^<a href="./support.html"^>%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%Help^</a^>
echo        ^<a href="./security.html"^>%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%%nbsp%Security^</a^> 
)>u:index.html
GOTO :EOF
```

Apart from the `&` problem pointed out in comments, the `^>^>` before the filename should *not* be escaped as you actually want to append to the file.

By setting a variable to the required string, you can avoid escaping each `&`

By parenthesising the `echo`es and redirecting the output with a redirector after the close-parenthesis you can avoid needing to nominate the output file on each line.

I used `>` as a redirector to create the file anew. You may wish to use `>>` to append. I also used a different drive for the output file.

You could also use

```
>>filename echo ......
```

By placing the redirection details at the start of the line, it's less likely to get lost.

You could use

```
 SET "nbsp2=^&nbsp;^&nbsp;"
```

or something similar to reduce the number of `%var%`s required to be `echo`ed.